# Twitter API: Get Followers +99

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

Using the twitter API (and OAuth) if i was to call for the user followers, (statuses/followers) i would be returned only 99 results.

Is there a way i can return 99, then call again starting at follower 100 then looping through this style of calling until the total number of followers has been returned?

Or just return ALL followers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify cursor parameter as described [in the API documrnation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0followers). E.g. specify cursor=-1 to request the first page and then use a next_cursor value returned in the first response:

```
  http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barackobama.xml?cursor=-1
  http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barackobama.xml?cursor=1300794057949944903
```

Comment: You get "Not authorized to use this endpoint" when you try these URLs.. I think they may have changed their API?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$trends_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/fawadghafoor.json";
$ch       = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trends_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlout  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($curlout, true);

foreach($response as $friends){
      $thumb = $friends['profile_image_url'];
      $url   = $friends['screen_name'];
      $name  = $friends['name'];
?>                         
<a title="<?php echo $name;?>" href="http://www.twitter.com/<?php echo $url;?>"><img class="photo-img" src="<?php echo $thumb?>" border="0" alt="" width="40" /></a>
    <?php  }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're using the right call. `followers/ids` gives you 5000 at a time (but it's just a list of ids). This call, too, uses the cursor to let you step through pages of users. You get a zero back when you have them all.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter API restricts us to make api Call for method followers/ids is 15 requests per 15 minutes. If you make more than this api will give you an error message that Rate Limit Reached.

For more information of twitter API rate Limit
Visit-https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1 and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits

Answer (score 0):

Twitter only allows a certain number of API requests per hour, and I *think* minute.  You might not be able to retrieve any more than 99 requests at once.

Comment: The total is 150 per hour. So he could get 100 people 150 times (or 5000 people 150 times, depending on the call he uses). This number is for the calls that don't need authorization. Calls that require authorization are tallied separately. You can request whitelisting for your app, but even that is not enough to go banging at the API willy-nilly, so if you expect a high-volume service, you need to do some caching.

Comment: But you make a good point. There are many accounts with many more than 15,000 followers. You'll use up all your API hits at once with them.

Comment: they are on a per OAuth user basis - if user_1 hits their limit.. they get errors, but user_2 will still be fine

Answer (score 0):

Though I asked this quite a while ago, I came back to building something quite similar recently (+ new programming skills).

I noticed Twitter API have a method to get **all** of a users followers (or followings) user ID's in one request. I found the best way was to `array_chunk` up the ID's into batches of 100 (and only take the first 30 arrays as I dont want to use all the users api requests that hour - they might want to actually tweet!). Then there is a method that allows you to get up to 100 users userinfo (from the view of the currently authenticated user) so I just do a loop (sleep a bit inbetween) and then you've got 30,000 twitter followers!

I would recommend doing this asynchronously in a queue system, as if you do this on the fly when the users requests a page on the site it could be very slow and you might be prone to a HTTP timeout. Also cache them like hell!

Sorry I didn't post any code, but hopefully this thought process will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cursor = -1;
$account_from = 'twitter_account';
do
{
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/' . $account_from .'json?cursor=' . $cursor);
    $accounts = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($accounts->users as $account)
    {

            array(
                ':twitter_id' => $account->id_str,
                ':account' => $account->screen_name,
                ':description' => $account->description,
            );
    }
    $cursor = $accounts->next_cursor;

}
while ($cursor > 0);
```

Comment: Could you please add even the tiniest bit of explanation for your answer? Additional information on how for *him* to incorporate it to his code would also be good.