# Get all followers of user on twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I am using twitter application in mywebsite.

I am using followers api of twitter.

I want to see all followers of particular user.

but it shows only 100 followers.I want to see all followers.

Please help me how can fetch all followers of user

Answer (score 3):

might find answer here:  [Twitter API: Get Followers +99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856074/twitter-api-get-followers-99)

Comment: how to get the next cursor value for fetching the list of all followers

Answer (score 0):

There are several useful videos you can watch. Check out this one for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0a6EXGLxVY

or search for "twitter harvesting or scraping".

There are also several services and tools. However I would not buy a tool. Its not worth it if you dont harvest regularly But maybe give those a shot, they seem fairly reasonable with their price:

http://myhelpster.com/scrape-twitter-followers-any-account/